# Glyphicons not working with bootstrap-sass in Angular

Tags: angularjs, sass, bootstrap-sass

I've had an issue with GlyphIcons not loading correctly when using this bower component: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

I tracked down the issue to finding an `@at-root` element being injected into my CSS file.

I was able to get glyph icons working by removing the element, IMHO this is a damn useless SASS selector that does not add much value in the context it was being used.

Once I tracked down the issue, I then looked at the issues register in their GIT repository and found this item that suggested that the version of SASS compiler needed to be at least 3.3. See: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/953.

I am on windows and just using bower components so I did a re-installation of Boostrap-Sass

```
bower install bootstrap-sass -g
```

But this did **not** resolve my problem.

I'm not sure what the issue is, I hope someone has a solution to getting the latest bootstrap sass working on a windows/node environment.

For now I have fixed the issue by find the 2 references to `@at-root` in folder bootstrap-sass-official and just removing them.

[image]

**Installed the latest version of Ruby**

[image]

Comment: Please try to update your sass version. It seems like this could be causing your problem. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/925

Comment: I don't see what the problem here is, upgrade to Sass 3.3 or greater and the problem is solved.  Not sure why you think reinstalling bootstrap-sass is going to change anything.

Comment: Because that does not seem to be easily achievable on windows. I have the latest version of ruby installed, which I assume has Sass 3.3, and I still have this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed this link http://awordpress.net/blog/install-sass-compass-manually-windows/ for doing manual install of SASS.

I'm not sure why I could not get compass to install (as per the link above) but it did not matter as the firth point in that link was all I needed to get SASS updated on a windows

```
gem install sass
```

[image]

Comment: Seems someone downgraded my answer without actually stating why, anyway this worked hopefully it is useful to someone else.